# what does " We have to flip the leadership playbook." mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idioms, figurative-language

> We have to flip the leadership playbook. ( From [TED](http://youtube.com/watch?v=Cxf_SRCcaGo))

What does this mean？ To learn from the metaphorical playbook or to upend it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't watched the video, but from the quote it would be the same as what Merriam Webster describes as ['flip the script'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flip#flip-the-script-anchor):

> **flip the script**
>
> *informal*
>
> : to achieve an outcome or adopt an approach that is opposite to or completely different from what has happened or been done previously

The tagline to the video on YouTube mentions:

> *Humility, transparency and urgency are the keys to successfully steering an organization — big or small — through the challenges that come your way*

So if "humility" wouldn't traditionally be seen as a leadership quality, but they've "flipped the script" (or "flipped the leadership playbook") and are taking a different approach.